# Is the Koch Snowflake a Compact Space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am taking an introductory topology class, and we recently defined the notion of compactness. Earlier in the chapter, the Koch snowflake is described, and I am wondering: is the Koch snowflake a compact set? Intuitively I think the answer is yes: it is <strike>an infinite union of closed sets</strike> (not necessarily closed) and its limiting area is bounded, so it is a bounded and closed set of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Am I just waiving my hands, or is this a solid argument?

Comment: An infinite union of closed sets is not necessarily closed. For example, $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{n}, 1] = (0, 1]$.

Comment: Don’t waive your hands: you might need them! :-)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelAlbanese, that was a slip on my part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The union of infinitely many closed sets is not necessarily closed. However, the Koch snowflake is compact: it’s the range of a continuous function defined on the compact set $[0,1]$, and continuous functions preserve compactness.

Comment: What is the continuous function between the two spaces? I am worried that just "saying" there is a continuous function between them is not enough.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154382/is-koch-snowflake-a-continuous-curve) and its answer.

Comment: @A.E: You’re welcome!